# Will correcting the timezone of a WordPress installation effect the search engine rankings of all the posts?

Tags: wordpress, google-ranking, penalty, timezone

I am using WordPress CMS. I had started my blog 2 years ago. Right now I have 284 blog posts in my sitemap. When I started my blog, I made a mistake while selecting time zone. I live in India my time zone should be `UTC+05:30` or Kolkata, but I have selected there `UTC-5:30` by mistake. Now I am getting the wrong published time in my every blog post.

If I make changes in time zone & correct it to `UTC+05:30` or Kolkata in WordPress>> general setting>> Time zone setup, will it create any problem for my all blog post ranking in Google search engine? Because after making changes in time zone, it will automatically make changes in “post sitemap” timing. and it also makes changes in Google search console.

If I change timezone Will Google remove my all blog posts from the search results?  Could it result in any other search engine penalty?